# Tile Drawing on Canvas based on file with ints

Tags: java, awt, paintcomponent, tile

So im trying to make a map based on a a file which has ints in it

```
1111111111
1000000001
1000000001
1000000001
1111111111
```

And so what i get the code to do is display a grass tile (32x32) for 1 and a dirt tile for 0.

This is my code for loading and differentiating between the 2.

```
protected void loadMapFile(String string) throws Exception {
    // TODO Load Map, Put into int array
    File f = new File(string);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line = in.readLine();

    cols = line.length();
    rows = count(string) + 1;
    System.out.println(rows);

    lines = new String[rows];
    map = new Image[cols][rows];
    mapMask = new int[cols][rows];

    while (line != null) {
        lines[counter] = line;
        counter++;
        line = in.readLine();
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
            mapMask[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(lines[y].substring(x, x + 1));
            System.out.print(mapMask[x][y]);
            setImageContent(x, y);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    mapCreated = true;

}




private void setImageContent(int x, int y) {
    switch (mapMask[x][y]) {
    case 0:// dirt
        map[x][y] = Images.DirtTile.getImage();
        break;
    case 1:// grass
        map[x][y] = Images.GrassTile.getImage();
        break;
    }
}
```

And on my paint method i draw it like so:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (mapCreated) {
        for (int y = 0; y < endRows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < endCols; x++) {
                g.drawImage(map[x][y], 0 + (x * 32), 0 + (y * 32),
                        32 + (x * 32), 32 + (y * 32), 0, 0, 32, 32, this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My question is, would you guys recomend this and also is there a easier way to render Tiles to the screen?

Comment: How do you load the `Image`s to `map`? BTW you can call `System.out.println()` without arguments for a new line ^^

Comment: @Pietu1998: I have an Images enum which contains all the tiles and their paths

Comment: But are `Image` _objects_ loaded to `map` individually, like `map[i][j] = <load image>` in a loop? Because in that case there would be an own `Image` instance for each tile in the map (better would be to load the images once and use the same objects for all tiles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should use your for loops to draw the tiles initially to a larger BufferedImage and save the BufferedImage to a class field.
- Then use drawImage to draw the single BufferedImage in `paintComponent(...)`. This will allow for much more efficient drawing.
- Unless of course your tiles change in rapid succession.

Another alternative is to put your tiles into ImageIcons and the Icons into an array of JLabel.  For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridExample extends JPanel {
   public static final int[][] MAP = {
      {1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2},
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2}
   };

   public static final Color[] COLORS = {};
   private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[MAP.length][MAP[0].length];

   public GridExample() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(MAP.length, MAP[0].length));
      for (int r = 0; r < labelGrid.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < labelGrid[r].length; c++) {
            labelGrid[r][c] = new JLabel();
            labelGrid[r][c].setIcon(Ground.getGround(MAP[r][c]).getIcon());
            add(labelGrid[r][c]);            
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GridExample mainPanel = new GridExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum Ground {
   DIRT(0, new Color(205,133, 63)), GRASS(1, new Color(0, 107, 60)), 
   WATER(2, new Color(29, 172, 214));
   private int value;
   private Color color;
   private Icon icon;

   private Ground(int value, Color color) {
      this.value = value;
      this.color = color;

      icon = createIcon(color);
   }

   private Icon createIcon(Color color) {
      int width = 24; // how to use const in enum? 
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, width, width);
      g.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }

   public Icon getIcon() {
      return icon;
   }

   public static Ground getGround(int value) {
      for (Ground ground : Ground.values()) {
         if (ground.getValue() == value) {
            return ground;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }

}
```

---

Example 2: a Grid that can change icons with mouse press:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridExample extends JPanel {
   private Ground[][] groundMap = {
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS,
               Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS,
               Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER },
         { Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS,
               Ground.GRASS, Ground.GRASS, Ground.DIRT, Ground.DIRT,
               Ground.DIRT, Ground.WATER, Ground.WATER }, };

   private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[groundMap.length][groundMap[0].length];

   public GridExample() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(groundMap.length, groundMap[0].length));
      for (int r = 0; r < labelGrid.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < labelGrid[r].length; c++) {
            labelGrid[r][c] = new JLabel();
            labelGrid[r][c].setIcon(groundMap[r][c].getIcon());
            add(labelGrid[r][c]);
         }
      }

      addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
   }

   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         Component comp = getComponentAt(mEvt.getPoint());
         for (int row = 0; row < labelGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < labelGrid[row].length; col++) {
               if (labelGrid[row][col] == comp) {
                  Ground ground = groundMap[row][col];
                  int mapCode = ground.getValue();
                  mapCode++;
                  mapCode %= Ground.values().length;
                  groundMap[row][col] = Ground.values()[mapCode];
                  labelGrid[row][col].setIcon(groundMap[row][col].getIcon());
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GridExample mainPanel = new GridExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum Ground {
   DIRT(0, new Color(205, 133, 63)), GRASS(1, new Color(0, 107, 60)), WATER(2,
         new Color(29, 172, 214));
   private int value;
   private Color color;
   private Icon icon;

   private Ground(int value, Color color) {
      this.value = value;
      this.color = color;

      icon = createIcon();
   }

   private Icon createIcon() {
      int width = 24;
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, width,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, width, width);
      g.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }

   public Icon getIcon() {
      return icon;
   }

   public static Ground getGround(int value) {
      for (Ground ground : Ground.values()) {
         if (ground.getValue() == value) {
            return ground;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }

}
```

Comment: well it changes when the character moves so when the user press thew direction keys, i still have to figure out how im going to do that though

Comment: Thanks but I'm drawing it onto a Canvas, so wouldnt the JLabel parts not work?

Comment: @Exikle: see edit 2. Don't use AWT classes whatever you do. Use only Swing classes else you're needlessly hampering the abilities of your program.